# getting receiver class void for NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

I know this has to be something super simple, but can't for the life of me figure it out. I can't get XCode to recognize NSWindow as an objective-c class. I have the following simple code:

HelloWorldAppDelegate.h

```
#import  <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "EAGLView_mac.h"

@interface HelloWorldAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow    *window;
    EAGLView    *glView;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow    *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet EAGLView    *glView;

@end
```

HelloWorldAppDelegate.m

```
#import "HelloWorldAppDelegate.h"
#import "EAGLView_mac.h"

@implementation HelloWorldAppDelegate
@synthesize window, glView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 480, 320);

    window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect: frame styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];

    //EAGL init code cut for brevity      

    [window setContent:glView];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

@end
```

When I try to compile XCode complains that NSWindow is a receiver type 'void' and not an objective-c class. None of the autocomplete functions popped up when I was typing up the code either. I get an actual error on the call to NSWindow alloc, and a warning on the other two calls to 'window' all complaining that window and/or NSWindow is a receiver type void. It also complains that the methods 'setContent' and 'makeKeyAndOrderFront' are not found? Am I missing an include somewhere?

Comment: If you create a brand new Cocoa App project with all of the default settings, does it have the same problem? If so, it's possible that your AppKit framework (either the one in /System/Library or the one in one of the Xcode SDKs) is broken… but I'd start by reinstalling Xcode and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the property attribute of the NSWindow and EAGLView outlets to either

- `(nonatomic, retain)`, if you're **not using ARC**
- `(weak)`, if you're **using ARC**

[The Objective-C Programming Language: Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html) explains this and states:

> assign
>   Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. This attribute is the default.
>   You use this attribute for **scalar** types such as NSInteger and CGRect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh and as you're using declared properties, note, that you can access these properties by self.window and self.glView respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I was working from a template file and didn't catch that those needed to be changed. However, that still doesn't fix the problem. Now it gives an error on the property attribute saying that a property with the 'retain' attribute must be an object type. It still refuses to acknowledge NSWindow.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is. Why are you actually allocating a NSWindow? As it is an IBOutlet the window is allocated and instatiated by the XIB.

Comment: I was allocating it through a XIB, but I had the same problem, I couldn't access it. So I deleted the xib and created my own window thinking that would solve it. Clearly it didn't. With the XIB in place, the window will pop up, but trying to access the 'window' property gives me the same warning as above.

Comment: Hm, that's really weird. When have the XIB in place, (not alloc init a window in code) and using the IBOutlet properties, have you made sure, that the Outlet is connected to the window property of File's Owner in IB? This is kind of messed up. I would recommend to start a new project. The template should bring the window outlet without you having to configure anything. Then you can access it in your methods with [self.window someMethod].